# How to check current week day is in between with the given week day range?

Tags: java, logic

How to implement the logic to validate that current week day[Saturday] coming between any given weekday range[Sunday:Friday].

### Program expectation

**Input** : weekday range expected

**Output** : current week day is coming between the given range or not.

Example:

## Case1: Consider current day is Sun and given range Sun:Sat

> according to my implementation logic below will be accepted.

## Case2: Consider current day is Sun and given range Mon:Sun

> now with current solution mon <= current_day(Sun) <= Sum, which is not
>   fully satisfy.

Does anyone have any idea how to implement this solution, I tried finding the solution online but nothing worth while I found.

The logic which I implemented:

```
// CURRENT DAY CALCULATION
Calendar currDate = Calendar.getInstance();
int currentDayInNo = currDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

// BIMAP FOR MAPPING OF DAYS NUMBER AND DAYS
static final ImmutableBiMap<String, Integer> DaysToNo =
           new ImmutableBiMap.Builder<String, Integer>()
               .put("Sun", 1)  
               .put("Mon", 2)  
               .put("Tue", 3)  
               .put("Wed", 4)  
               .put("Thu", 5)  
               .put("Fri", 6)  
               .put("Sat", 7)  
               .build();
if (currentDayInNo >= DaysToNo.get(scheduleStartDay) && currentDayInNo <= DaysToNo.get(scheduleEndDay)) {
        logger.info("First acceptance criteria meet: " + "Today's day : " + LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek()+ " is come between " + scheduleStartDay + " and " + scheduleEndDay);
} else {
        logger.info("First acceptance criteria not meet: " + "Today's day : "+ LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek() + "  is not come between " + scheduleStartDay + " and "+ scheduleEndDay);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would like more details on what your expected output should be , are you just checking whether the day is is within a sequence of days, let's say we are checking if Thursday is between Tuesday and Friday or do you want to check whether it is within a specific week of the month.

I believe the error comes in the comparison that you have tried on, 
Here's how it works now, let's say the day is Sunday which is an int of 1, and you're comparing a start date of Monday which is an int of 2 till Sunday which is 1. You're going in descending order,

So the if fails in the first evaluation of the && , where 1 is not >= 2 ;

So, if the end day value is smaller than the start day value , you can change the end day value by adding the size of the map, since logically it signifies the start of a new week, making the value 8, then you will have to change the currentDate with the size of the map as well if its value is smaller than the start day value this will pass the && evaluation.

```
    if (scheduleEndDay < scheduleStartDay) {
    scheduleEndDay += DaysToNo.size();
}

if (currentDayInNo <  scheduleStartDay) {
    currentDayInNo += DaysToNo.size();
}
```

Comment: updated my question to make it more clear, what to know if any java build in library to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your requirements correctly, do you want to check weekday between consecutive weeks?

```
// CURRENT DAY CALCULATION
Calendar currDate = Calendar.getInstance();
int currentDayInNo = currDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

// BIMAP FOR MAPPING OF DAYS NUMBER AND DAYS
//@formatter:off
static final ImmutableBiMap<String, Integer> DaysToNo =
           new ImmutableBiMap.Builder<String, Integer>()
               .put("Sun", 1)  
               .put("Mon", 2)  
               .put("Tue", 3)  
               .put("Wed", 4)  
               .put("Thu", 5)  
               .put("Fri", 6)  
               .put("Sat", 7)  
               .build();

int startDateInNo = DaysToNo.get(scheduleStartDay);
int endDateInNo = DaysToNo.get(scheduleEndDay);
int daysInWeek = DaysToNo.size();

if (endDateInNo < startDateInNo) {
    endDateInNo += daysInWeek;
}

if (currentDayInNo <  startDateInNo) {
    currentDatInNo += daysInWeek;
}

if (currentDayInNo >= startDateInNo && currentDayInNo <= endDateInNo) {
        logger.info("First acceptance criteria meet: " + "Today's day : " + LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek()+ " is come between " + scheduleStartDay + " and " + scheduleEndDay);
} else {
        logger.info("First acceptance criteria not meet: " + "Today's day : "+ LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek() + "  is not come between " + scheduleStartDay + " and "+ scheduleEndDay);
}
```

Comment: updated my question to make it more clear, what to know if any java build in library to implement this?

Comment: I think for second if condition we have to increase the currentDatInNo not the startDateInNo as per previous comment.

Comment: Indeed it should be currentDatInNo, fixed that